# Linux: an easy and elegant way to find all files with acl set?

Tags: acl

I want to find all files with acl set.
I know this dirty solution: for find all files with acl set in dir. /etc

```
 sudo ls -lhR /etc|grep +
```

Someone know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy and elegant is quite a high bar to reach and your dirty solution fails if you have filenames with `+` in it (say c++).

The alternative is using `getfacl` recursively, skipping files that don't have ACL

```
getfacl -Rs /your/dir | grep "# file:"
```

That will list them and the grep keeps just the filenames.

Comment: That fails if there are ACLs for users or groups whose name ends in `file` though. Also note that `getfacl` transforms some characters in the file paths (newline becomes `\012`, bacslashes are doubled at least)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

With [`sfind`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html) or the `find` builtin of the [`bosh`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html) shell, it's just:

```
sfind . -acl
```

```
bosh -c 'find . -acl'
```

> ```
> -acl The primary evaluates as true if  the  file  has  addi-
>      tional  ACLs defined.  On platforms that do not support
>      ACLs or where sfind does not yet support ACLs, the pri-
>      mary   always   evaluates  as  false.   Currently  only
>      Solaris, Linux and FreeBSD is supported.
> ```

Both `sfind` and `bosh` are shipped as part of [Schily-Tools](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/).

To get something similar with the [`getfacl` command typically found on GNU systems](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl/), building up on [Eduardo's answer](/a/654850), we'd need to decode the file field (where `getfacl` encodes some byte values with `\ooo` representations and `\` as `\\`) with something like:

```
getfacl -Rs  . | perl -nle '
  if (/^# file: (.*)/) {
    print $1 =~ s{\\(\\|[0-7]{3})}{
      $1 eq "\\" ? "\\" : chr oct $1}ger
  }'
```

To do something with that list of files, as we can't use `find`'s `-exec` here, you'd want to print the list NUL delimited:

```
getfacl -Rs  . | perl -nl0e '
  if (/^# file: (.*)/) {
    print $1 =~ s{\\(\\|[0-7]{3})}{
      $1 eq "\\" ? "\\" : chr oct $1}ger
  }'
```

So you can for instance pipe it to `xargs -r0 some-command` or store in an array with `array=( ${(0)"$(cmd)"} )` (zsh) or `readarray -td '' < <(cmd)` (bash 4.4+).

Comment: `Schily-Tools` asks for root permissions to install and then modify (as it chooses) root owned files in several directories. Not something I would allow in my systems. But YMMV and you have a lower security bar.

Comment: If you assume linux + perl, you can probably combine `File::Find` and `syscall(SYS_[l]getxattr, "system.posix_acl_{access,default}")`.

Comment: @Isaac, how to build schily-tools, perl or acl or any of the software involved in this Q&A from source is beyond the scope of this Q&A, but if you want to build it yourself and use `smake install` to install it outside system locations, you can have a look at the `README.compile` in the source tarball. If you have concerns about the security of that software, I'd suggest you bring it up to the maintainer, but here it sounds more like a packaging concern.